# Custom domain is not working in salesforce

Tags: mydomain, custom-domain

*I have created below CName in GoDaddy.

```
CName: Host: www, Points To: mydomain.reg.[Organization Id].live.siteforce.com, TTL: 2000 SECONDS

Txt : Host: @ , Points To: Salesforce Organization Id, TTL: 2000 SECONDS
```

After CName and Txt configuration, i have created www.mydomain.reg custom domain in salesforce and added this custom domain to force.com site (mysite) via custom URL. However, when i run "www.mydomain.reg" url on browser i am getting the exception.

**Note:**I have created CName in GoDaddy 40 hours before.
Can anybody help me to fix the above issue.*

please check the below screen shot*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've badly anonymized your data, I can't really tell where there's a problem.

Your data *should* look as follows:

```
CName: Host: www, Points To: www.mydomainname.com.00DXXXXXXXXXXXX.live.salesforce.com, TTL: 2000 SECONDS
Txt: Host: @, Points To: 00DXXXXXXXXXXXX, TTL: 2000 seconds
```

The full domain name must be added before the org ID.

This is a configuration issue since it has been over 40 hours since registration.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have added more details on above questions. Can you pelase review it and let me know your thouths.

Comment: I have added full domain name before org id as per Godaddy technial support team. Host: www, Points To: www.mydomainname.com.00DXXXXXXXXXXXX.live.salesforce.com, TTL: 2000 SECONDS. However, still i am getting the same issue. Do i need to do any configuration in site.com in salesforce?

Comment: @Ramya No, you should be fine, just remember that there's a 2000 TTL, so it'll take up to 34 minutes to cycle.

Comment: I have changed TTL from 2000 to 600. thank you.

Comment: I already (2 days before) added full domain before organization id in GoDaddy but it was not work because "txt" configuration is not there in DNS. So, as per Godaddy techincal team help i have removed full domain name before organizatiioin id becuase already Domain name is "mydomainname" in Godaddy. Now i have added full domain name before Organization Id in DNS and it is working fine. Thank you for your very much your help.

Comment: @Ramya Congrats! I'm happy you were able to get it working.